# ggplot add annotation_custom() linesGrob() with negative slope

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Since facet_zoom2 isnt working anymore, i am looking for a way to display two graphs side by side while highlighting the zoomed area on the left plot.

I tried to build this shapes by hand.
However, the annotation_custom() funktion seems to work only with a positive slope, no matter what xmin, ymin, xmax and ymax are.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(grid)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(hp)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = gear, y = value) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_rect(xmin = 2.9, ymin =50, xmax =5.1, ymax =100, fill = "transparent", color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1,200)) -> p1

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(hp)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = gear, y = value) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(50,100)) -> p2

p1 + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,5,0,0), "cm")) +
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin =5.2, ymin =100, xmax =7, ymax=200) + 
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin =5.2, ymin =50, xmax =7, ymax=0) + 
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin =5.2, ymin =0, xmax =7, ymax=50) +
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin =7, ymin =0, xmax =5.2, ymax=50) +
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), xmin =7, ymin =50, xmax =5.2, ymax=0) +
  coord_cartesian(clip="off") + p2
```

As you can see in the result, the last 4 linesGrob are resulting in the same line: On with a positive slope. How is it possible to draw from up-left to down-right?

[image: result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `grob = linesGrob()` without passing any arguments to `linesGrob`, the result will always slope upwards left-to-right, because its default `x` argument is set to `c(0, 1)` and it default `y` argument is set to `c(0, 1)` - in a sense it is just a square picture of a 45 degree line sloping upwards left-to-right. By rescaling its x and y dimensions you can convert it to anything from a horizontal to a vertical line, but it will always be upsloping left-to-right between these two extremes.

However, the x and y co-ordinates of a `linesGrob` can be changed to whatever you like, to draw arbitrary line shapes. The grob is drawn on whatever rectangle you set according to `ymin`, `ymax`, `xmin` and `xmax`. The coordinates you set in `linesGrob` represent the space within this rectangle, with `x = 0, y = 0` being the bottom left corner, and `x = 1, y = 1` being the top right corner.

Just change the default y values to `c(1, 0)`, and we have a downsloping line that you can then rescale with `annotation_custom`:

```r
p1 + theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,5,0,0), "cm")) +
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(), 
                    xmin =5.2, ymin = 100, xmax = 7, ymax = 200) + 
  annotation_custom(grob = linesGrob(y = c(1, 0)),
                    xmin =7, ymin = 0, xmax = 5.2, ymax = 50) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") + p2
```

[image]